# Calling a UIApplicationDelegate method from a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a simple iPhone application that is very similar to the Page Control example provided by Apple.  It creates a group of UIViewControllers dynamically, then adds them to a ScrollView.

When a button is touched on one of these views, I need to be able to call a method back in the UIApplicationDelegate.  It will then do some calculations, and generate a new set of views to display.

I'm not sure how to make this happen.  It would seem like this would work, but it doesn't:

```
[[self superview] doSomething];
```

What am I missing?  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[[(MyAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] doSomething]
```

Replace MyAppDelegate with the name of your App Delegate class

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Though I should mention -- for other beginners like myself -- I also needed to include the header file for the AppDelegate into my ViewController:

#import "MyAppDelegate.h"

Comment: I had to use `[(MyAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] doSomething]`. (The cast was in the wrong place.)